# Setting Up Django and React

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I am using `WebPack` to setup Django and React. So far, I have generated a `bundle` and I am trying to reference it in my template:

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% block main %}
<div id="App1"></div>
{% render_bundle 'vendors' %}
{% render_bundle 'App1' %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, Django can't seem to find the correct `bundle` files and I get a `404` error shown in the diagram below. Did I initialize everything correctly in the `settings.py`?

[image]

EDIT:

`webpack-stats-local.json`: # Generated correctly from config files

```
{"status":"done","chunks":{"App1":[{"name":"App1-a1f17f437b3aacf3188f.js","path":"/Users/andyxu/Documents/my_website/my_website/static/bundles/local/App1-a1f17f437b3aacf3188f.js"}],"vendors":[{"name":"vendors.js","path":"/Users/andyxu/Documents/my_website/my_website/static/bundles/local/vendors.js"}]}}
```

`print(STATIC_ROOT)`
    ==>
    `/Users/andyxu/Documents/my_website/my_website/static`

Comment: Could you please include settings.py with STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: @PierreOcinom I have shown everything in the screen shot except STATIC_ROOT. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in django but you can simply call your vendor and App1 files with script tag.

vendor and App1 files are the only required code to load react appropriate data.

In your case check if you are accessing path to javascript files correctly. try to provide absolute path to vendor files and see if it loads?

Comment: No, it seems that his webpack setup is OK (except for the missing bundle stats file - at least I don't see it on the screenshot). And he surely can't use `<script>` as the hashes would be different every time. That's the whole point of `webpack-bundle-tracker` + `django-webpack-loader` - to communicate the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings look normal, but those 404 indicate that Django can't find the static files, even though they're there.

The most likely cause is some path misconfiguration. While `staticfiles.views.serve` should consider all `STATICFILES_DIR`s, I'm not exactly sure it does. Either way, try to define `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_website', 'static')` explicitly.

Also, add a temporary `print(STATIC_ROOT)` (or use debugger) to see the actual path - maybe your `BASE_DIR` is off. It's very easy to miss a directory level there.

Oh, and from your screenshot it seems that there is no `webpack-stats-local.json` in `bundles/local/`. Check your `BundleTracker` confuguration, it should approximately look like this:

```
new BundleTracker({
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'my_website/static/bundles'),
    filename: 'webpack-stats-local.json'
})
```

Without a proper `path` there it'll silently fail. Just had this issue the other day - no warnings whatsoever, just the file wasn't anywhere to be found.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I actually do have a `webpack-stats-local.json` file, just wasn't shown in the picture. Everything seems to be in order. I printed out the variables and everything but it still can't find it. I will make some edits.

Comment: @anderish: Odd, your settings look good, and `STATIC_ROOT` is correct. Can you try putting `test.txt` file in `my_website/static` and checking if `http://localhost:8000/static/test.txt` works? If it does, but bundles are still 404ing - I just can't think of any reason, except, maybe, for filesystem permissions (but that would be really strange case). If not - check your URLconfs where you enable [`...staticfiles.views.serve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view), maybe something isn't right there.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get a 404 error `http://localhost:8000/static/test.txt`. My `urls.py`: `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('main.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: I'm sort of ashamed to not being able to figure it out, but it all looks just fine. Almost exactly like I have it in a working project here. Must be some small detail... Maybe `DEBUG` isn't `True`? Personally, I'd fire a debugger, put a breakpoint at [`serve`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py#L31), do an HTTP request for test.txt and trace execution step by step, checking out where it looks for the files and why it fails.

Comment: Haha, don't be, thanks a lot for trying, I really appreciate it. I meant that the `static/test.txt` didn't work.